# Requirement for the exponent generation during DH protocol

Tags: diffie-hellman

The setting is classic DH protocol. Alice computes $A = g^a \bmod p$. Alice then sends $A$ to Bob. Then Bob will send $B = g^b \bmod p$ to Alice.

Are there any requirements for the values $a$ and $b$ besides they should be greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$, $A=g^a$ and $B=g^b$ are made public, everyone could repeat the same operation and brute force DH with small exponents.

There are already many responses:

[link to security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/is-there-a-key-length-definition-for-dh-or-dhe)

[link to crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/what-should-be-the-size-of-a-diffie-hellman-private-key)

Summary: considering a security level of $n$, it is advised to use exponents of at least $2n$ bits.