# Comparing Diffie Hellman and EC Diffie Hellman sizes

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

So, I am currently trying to understand the differences between **DH** and **ECDH**. I understand the basics between how the two algorithms work, however, I do not clearly understand how to compare the security of one to another, meaning the size of the **DH key** used vs the **EC curve size** used.

The question thus is, what **DH key sizes** correspond to which **EC curve sizes**?, and how can we effectively compare these two sizes?

Comment: This doesn't have and easy answer, see: https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/

Comment: ... where DH is sometimes mentioned as the "Discrete Logarithm Problem" or "DLP"...

Comment: Although you could look at
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62013/
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25577/ 
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/
and next door 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101044/ 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59190/
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/ 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/ 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48300/